# Can't update Django ArrayField

Tags: python, django

I have a class in my model.py as

```py
class Views(models.Model):
    X = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(blank = True))
    Y = ArrayField(models.DecimalField(blank = True,max_digits=2, decimal_places=2))
```

I entered the default value of X and Y as [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0].
But when I try to update the value of X or Y array, it doesn't really get updated.

shell commands are:

```
>>> from productsHome.models import Views
>>> x = Views.objects.all()
>>> x
<QuerySet [<Views: Views object (5)>]>
>>> x[0]
<Views: Views object (5)>
>>> x[0].X
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> x[0].X = [1,2,2,1]
>>> x[0].X
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>>
```

Why isn't my x[0].X is getting updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why isn't my `x[0].X` is getting updated?

Because you make a new query, and thus retrieve the value in the database. In order to update *persistently* (at the database side), you need to save the object that was updated. For example with:

```
x = Views.objects.all()
x0 = x[0]
x0.X = [1,2,2,1]
x0.save()

# …
print(x[0].X)
```